# Highchart throws errors when zoom out and hover point

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm trying to send **x** point from chart to a map so it can synchronize when hover the point. And it works properly when I don't zoom out and hover the point.
[image]

**But when zoom out and hover the points, it throws error**

[image]

**Reproduce code**: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-river-l1d3g?file=/package.json
I need to get **x** point so I can pass to my map component. That's why I set currentMarker to **x** point

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor?

Comment: hi @SebastianWędzel, I've attached a reproduce code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your code with some minor changes - chart config is defined in the state (as it is recommended to use the React Wrapper) and it seems that everything works fine.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-imzhv3?file=index.js

API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

Comment: thanks, the solution works. However, I have a question. Some trips work fine as the way I did before and a few throw errors although they use the same script. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @jasonB without reproduction of the issue and debugging the code it's hard to say what could have an impact on it.